# How to download file from SkyDrive on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I am using sample from https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK but it isn't working. I managed to run the PhotoSkyOnTheGo project, but after logging in I get 3 exceptions:

- A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll

What am I doing wrong or what source code should I use?

Comment: I am just running the sample project. I have provided proper client_id and referenced needed dll's After logging in to the SkyDrive the app is asking for access for my data, when I confirm there is a black screen and three mentioned before exceptions in the Visual Studio output window.

Comment: I noticed that LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs has the following error: `invalid_request: Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException: The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter, unless the app is configured as a mobile app. If you're the client application developer and you're creating a mobile app, you must configure it as one through the application management site at https://manage.dev.live.com/.` Its weird couse I have provided client_id...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `Mobile client app` setting to `yes` in manage.dev.live.com in`My applications > yourApp > API Settings` tab